# Getting all files and subfolders in given path - language compatibility in C/C++

Tags: c++, c, encoding, filesystems

So basically I need to list all of files and subfolders and files inside them etc till all paths has been inspected, read data from every single object and pack it all into a single file.

I did not want to use boost or minizip because it seems too much for something so easy so I just wrote it myself via dirent - everything works fine I just have problem with directories and files with non ANSI character in titles (I'm from Poland) like ąęóźż etc. 
I can open them without problem and read all data from them but when I pack their's filename to std::string - it gets corrupted and happend to be for example:

TEST~1 instead of TESTąę

How I pack files and directories to single file:

I read content of main directory via dirent, if I find file - I just read it's path and data to strucutre and if I find another directory - I just read it's path to structure and call searching function recursively on that directory.

To reading and writting file I use fopen,fwrite,fread.

Just a note that data inside files is being written without problems - all special characters are stored without problems.

Any help with that would be really appreciated.

Code:

```
#include <list>
#include <string>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <cstdio>
#include <windows.h>

typedef struct {
    std::string path;
    unsigned lenght_of_path;
    char type;
    unsigned size;
    char *data;
} single_element;



int pack(std::string root_directory, std::list<single_element> *all_elements)
//packs all files and subfolder and files and subfolder inside them etc into a std::list of structures
//please don't mind 0 error checks but I just want to get that language thing first
{
    single_element temp;
    temp.data = NULL;
    FILE *processed;

    DIR *directory;
    struct dirent *ent;
    if ((directory = opendir(root_directory.c_str())) != NULL)
    {
        while ((ent = readdir(directory)) != NULL)
        {
            std::string actual_path = root_directory;
            std::string packed_file = ent->d_name;
            if (packed_file != "." && packed_file != "..") //ignore .. and . in listing
            {
                if (ent->d_type == 16384) //if we found a directory
                {
                    actual_path += "\\";
                    actual_path += packed_file;
                    temp.data = NULL;
                    temp.type = 'D'; // D is for directory, used later when extracting
                    temp.path = actual_path;
                    temp.lenght_of_path = actual_path.length();
                    temp.size = 0;
                    all_elements->push_back(temp);
                    pack(actual_path,all_elements); //recursively scan subfolder
                }
                else //we got file - I know there also can be other things as symbolic link but its only for test and I'm going to fix it once it works 
                {
                    actual_path += "\\";
                    actual_path += packed_file;
                    processed = fopen(actual_path.c_str(),"rb");
                    if (processed != NULL)
                    {
                        temp.path = actual_path;
                        temp.lenght_of_path = actual_path.length();
                        temp.type = 'F'; //F is for FILE;
                        fseek (processed,0,SEEK_END);
                        temp.size = ftell(processed);
                        all_elements->push_back(temp);
                        all_elements->back().data = new char[all_elements->back().size];
                        rewind(processed);
                        fread(all_elements->back().data,all_elements->back().size,1,processed);
                        fclose(processed);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    closedir (directory);
    return 0;
}

int save(std::string file_name, std::list<single_element> all_elements)
//write all_elements to single file
{
    file_name += ".pak";
    FILE *packed = fopen(file_name.c_str(),"wb");
    int ammount  = all_elements.size();
    fwrite((const void*)&ammount,sizeof(int),1,packed); //fist write how many elements there are to be packed
    for (std::list<single_element>::iterator i = all_elements.begin(); i != all_elements.end(); i++) //write each element
    {
        fwrite((const void*)&i->lenght_of_path,sizeof(unsigned),1,packed);
        fwrite(i->path.c_str(),i->lenght_of_path,1,packed);
        fwrite((const void*)&i->type,sizeof(char),1,packed);
        if (i->type == 'F') //if its file write also data and it's size
        {
            fwrite((const void*)&i->size,sizeof(unsigned),1,packed);
            fwrite(i->data,i->size,1,packed);
        }

    }
    fclose(packed);
    return 0;
}

int load(std::string file, std::list<single_element> *all_elements)
//load elements from file to list of structures
{
    char *buf = NULL;
    file += ".pak";
    FILE *packed = fopen(file.c_str(),"rb");
    single_element temp;
    int ammount;
    fread((void*)&ammount,sizeof(int),1,packed); //first read how many elements there are
    for (int i = 0; i < ammount; i++)
    {
        fread((void*)&temp.lenght_of_path,sizeof(unsigned),1,packed);
        buf = new char[temp.lenght_of_path+1];
        fread(buf,temp.lenght_of_path,1,packed);
        buf[temp.lenght_of_path] = '\0';
        temp.path = buf;
        delete buf;
        buf = NULL;
        fread((void*)&temp.type,sizeof(char),1,packed);
        all_elements->push_back(temp);
        if (temp.type == 'F') //if its file, also read its data and size
        {
            fread((void*)&all_elements->back().size,sizeof(unsigned),1,packed);
            all_elements->back().data = new char[all_elements->back().size];
            fread(all_elements->back().data,all_elements->back().size,1,packed);
        }
        else //else we got directory so just write 0 to size and NULL to data
        {
            all_elements->back().size = 0;
            all_elements->back().data = NULL;
        }
    }
    fclose(packed);
    return 0;
}

int extract(std::string root_directory, std::list<single_element> all_elements)
{
    CreateDirectory(root_directory.c_str(),NULL); //create root directory
    std::list<single_element>::iterator i = all_elements.begin();
    while (i != all_elements.end()) //first create all directories
    {
        if (i->type == 'D') //if we got a directory create it and erase from list
        {
            CreateDirectory(i->path.c_str(),NULL);
            i = all_elements.erase(i);
        }
        else ++i;
    }
    i = all_elements.begin();
    while (i != all_elements.end()) //now extract all files
    {
        FILE *extracted;
        extracted = fopen(i->path.c_str(),"wb");
        fwrite(i->data,i->size,1,extracted);
        fclose(extracted);
        ++i;
    }
    return 0;

}

int main()
{
    std::list<single_element> all;
    std::string root = "Test";
    pack(root,&all);
    save(root,all);
    load(root,&all);
    extract(root,all);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why to give so much irrelevant information, instead of providing code sample showing your problem?

Comment: `I did not want to use boost or minizip because it seems too much for something so easy` If it were easy, why are you having trouble with it?

Comment: Perhaps he considers boost to be too much library for what he considers should be a trivial task?

Comment: `TEST~1` vs. `TESTąę` hints that the code reading the filename is limited to 8.3 characters - maybe some old library code.  Best to show your code.

Comment: On which operating system and which filesystem? Standard C does not know about directories....

Comment: System is Windows, added code to original post. 
I'm going to be away for couple of days so I will make sure to check when I'm back.
Take care guys and thanks for answers so far and for any that will come.

Answer (score 0):

I have 3 suggestions:

1)

If you want to traverse the directory structure to find all files and directories and read their contents, you can use the file tree walk function.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ftw.h>

int callback_function(const char *name, const struct stat *s, int type) 
{
    // Here you can read the filename and contents of a file and save it in your own format.

    printf("%s\n", name);
    // type can have one of the following values and meaning:

    // FTW_F    File
    // FTW_D    Directory
    // FTW_DNR  Directory not readable
    // FTW_SL   Symbolic link
    // FTW_NS   The object is NOT a symbolic link and is one for which stat() could not be executed

    return 0;
}

int main() 
{
    ftw(".", callback_function, 1);
    return 0;
}
```

2)

Use libtar http://www.feep.net/libtar/ to concatenate the files into a single file using a standard file format.

3)

Rely on an external executable like tar, zip, rar etc and call it using the system() function call.